# Question about reduction of spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider theorem 5 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Lfg-Span_and_Bases.pdf). It is the statement

> If $v_1,...,v_n$ span $V$ then they may be reduced to a basis of $V$.

I am wondering about why the proof proceeds with a distinguished step one. Can you tell me if the following would also be a valid proof:

Let $S = \{v_1, ...,v_n\}$. If $S$ is linearly independent there is nothing more to do. If $S$ is dependent then there is $k$ so that $v_k$ may be written as a linear combination of $S \setminus \{v_k\}$. Hence $span(S) = span(S \setminus \{v_k\})$. Set $S = S \setminus \{v_k\}$ and repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs are the same, the difference is kind of in the "algorithmic" side. In the link you provided, the vectors are treated in order (from $v_1$ to $v_n$), whereas in your proof you didn't mention in which order you would take $v_k$ at each step, and that's because this order doesn't matter at all.

Besides, you always have to be careful with the "repeat the procedure" thing, you should perform a proper induction if you want to be formal!